# Node-js concurrency in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, backend

I know that nodejs is single threaded so to enable it to handle simulatanious request I should be using clustering or that's what I hope so.

**Questions**:

1-Without Clustering ,Heroku can handle 1 request at a time so this means the same endpoint won't run in parallel multiple times right?

2-Is it a good architecture to make one cluster handle sign up requests for example and other cluster handle my app logic?

Comment: 1. It does not depend on Heroku. It depends on your programming. Usually however requests are handled asynchronously so it can handle multiple requests at a time. 2. Depends. Microservices and scalability of microservices are generally a good idea but Heroku isn't suited for this task (you only get one port, customizability is limited).

Comment: Thanks for your reply regarding the first question if the endpoint doesnt have promises therefore it won't be able to run the same endpoint in parallel with each other right